# Rails method global params kind_in error when upgraded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, legacy

I've recently done an rails and ruby upgrade, we don't have strong params in the app (I know it's legacy).

So the way it's done in the app we have the following

```rb
def all_params_permitted(this_params = nil)
  this_params = params if this_params == nil
  this_params.permit!

  this_params.each do |i, v|
    if v.kind_in?([Hash, ActionController::Parameters])
      all_params_permitted(v)
    end
  end
end
```

Which loops through all params and just accepts everything, `all_params_permitted` is called throughout the app I would love to add strong params but that's a no-go for now.

The issue in the above method is `kind_in?` the upgrade I did for this app was `rails 5.0.3` to `rails 6.1+` and went from `ruby 2.2.6` to `ruby 3.0.1` so I'm not sure why `kind_in?` has stopped working. This is an old app (built-in `rails 2`) so not sure if this has been deprecated.

Any help here would be great.

**Edit**

I have tried `kind_of?` but no dice.

Comment: _"kind_in error when upgraded"_ – when asking for help with an error, please include the error message and all relevant parts of the stacktrace.

Comment: I'd also just point out that this method screams "security vulnerability"!!...  If you're ever doing something like `user.update(params)` in the code, you might be vulnerable to privilege escalation.

Comment: Yeah I know that Tom, which is why I want to replace it with strong params. But adding strong params would be “too big of a code change” hence the question to fix what we have as I was very confused haha. Turns out we have a ton of custom code in the app as well extended ruby (not joking) including added a yes a ‘kind_in’ method which is why there’s no reference as it’s completely custom and we have a lot of this going on which I was unaware of it when I created this question haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `kind_in?`, also didn't find any reference to that method, also as you have not posted the error so not sure about your issue. `is_a?`, `kind_of?`, `instance_of?` are few methods that check the object class but they check only a single class. Looking at your code one option for your condition could be:

```
if [Hash, ActionController::Parameters].include?(v.class)
```

which will check if it belongs to one of these classes.

Comment: Note that your example strictly checks for instances of those classes. It would return `false` for instances of subclasses like ActiveSupport's `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Comment: @Stefan Yes but actually this is op's code, I have just changed it to work for his case

Answer (score 2):

> the upgrade I did for this app was rails 5.0.3 to rails 6.1+ and went from ruby 2.2.6 to ruby 3.0.1

This is asking for trouble. [It is strongly advised to try upgrading one minor version at a time](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-0-to-rails-5-1) (e.g. rails 5.0 --> 5.1 --> 5.2 --> 6.0 --> 6.1), otherwise you're very likely to break things with little information on why it's stopped working/how to fix it.

Likewise for ruby versions... At an **absolute minimum** I'd postpone the final upgrade to ruby v3 until your application works fine under ruby 2.7.

> I'm not sure why `kind_in?` has stopped working

Nor am I, because that's a custom method. You haven't show us how it's defined, and nor have you shown us the error message, so it's impossible for me to say with confidence what's gone wrong.

My **guess** is that it's implemented something like this:

```
class Object
  def kind_in?(classes)
    classes.any? { |c| self.kind_of?(c) }
  end  
end
```

i.e. it's a little wrapper around [the built-in `kind_of?` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F).

And with that said, I still have no idea why this would have "stopped working" due to a ruby and/or rails upgrade.